# Continue with old Health policy with current employer

Tags: united-states, health-insurance, law

I am from Indiana. I want to change my current Employer. I have a Group Policy from my current Employer. So I want to ask that Can I continue with my Old Group Policy with new Employer..?? or have to purchase new policy from new employer.

Comment: This depends on the terms of your current Group Policy. Most policies are for 1 year and renewed. Most employer sponsored policies lapse when you terminate employment. If its a voluntary Group policy purchased by you, at times the term could be carried over for remaining period. It is best you check the terms of current Policy. Further you may not be able to join the Group Policy of new employer in between and may be left without cover.

Comment: I've never personally seen a policy in the US like the one that @Dheer mentions. End of the current month is common.  End of year would be extremely unusual.  Maybe this is mixing the policy itself between the employer and the insurance with the individual participation in that plan?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you can continue your previous employer group policy under COBRA provisions for a certain period of time. However, the premiums will be your personal responsibility and will be paid with after-tax money.

Unless that plan allows multiple employers to participate (which is something I've never heard of), you won't be able to have your new employer pay into the old plan. You may try negotiate more salary to compensate your extra costs, if it is so important to you to keep your old plan, but I'm not sure it will be worth it.

Answer (score 2):

In the last decade I have only seen somebody want to keep their "old" plan in a few cases. In those cases the old plan was desired because they were a government or military retiree and the new company offered them a bonus if they declined the insurance. One company gave everybody a stipend for insurance, so if they  didn't spend it all they could keep the balance. In another case they were given an extra week of vacation.

When you leave your old company they will terminate your insurance coverage. In some cases it is when you walk out the door; in other cases it goes to the end of the week; in others the end of the month. You will be able to continue the coverage via COBRA for 18 months. But be prepared to pay. You will not only pay the employee part, but you will also pay the employer part of the policy premium. If you don't see any extra cash from the new job, your insurance cots could double, or more.

After COBRA runs out, or sooner if COBRA is too expensive, you could switch to an individual policy with the same insurance company. This could be offered directly from the insurance company, or though your state or the federal exchange. Depending on your situation you could get a credit for part of the premium. You would have to determine if those individual policies would meet your requirements.

When you show up for your first day of work with the new company they will open what is typically a 30 day window for you to enroll in their insurance policy. Once that window closes you will have to wait until their next enrollment window to join the new companies insurance. For many US companies the open annual season is in the late fall to start on January 1st, but not all companies follow that plan. The decision to decline you might have to live with for 11 months.

The IRS does allow people to make insurance changes after a life event, so when the COBRA policy runs out after 18 months they would let you join the policy offered by the new company. But if you didn't go COBRA, you might be limited to only those annual open seasons.

Comment: I believe providing incentive for declining coverage is no longer legal

Comment: The last time i saw it offered was for the 2015 calendar year, I am no longer with that company.